# GCE snapshot vs VMware snapshot

Tags: google-compute-engine, snapshot

I am now to GCE and now looking for a way to backup our GCE VM.
As per Google documentation, it seems that Google recommends performing the VM backup by creating snapshots. However, in VMware, using snapshots as a backup method is not recommended as the delta disk will grow and the system may be unstable.
I wonder if the way GCE handle snapshot different with Vmware so in GCE, snapshots can be used as a backup method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use snapshots as backup. You can take backup of a persistent disk by creating snapshots even while they are attached to running instances. Snapshots are global resources, so you can use them to restore data to a new disk or instance within the same project. You can also share snapshots across projects.

You can refer to the public documentation of GCP on persistent disk snapshots: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots

In GCP you can use the instance templates to create VMs and you can use it as backup for creating VMs when you need.Instance templates define the machine type, boot disk image or container image, labels, and other instance properties. You can then use an instance template to create a MIG or to create individual VMs. Instance templates are a convenient way to save a VM instance's configuration so you can use it later to create VMs or groups of VMs.

You can refer to the public documentation of GCP on Instance templates : https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates

Comment: Is that mean the way Google handles the snapshot is different from Vmware.

Answer (score 0):

**Note on backups and persistent disk snapshots**

"If you create a snapshot of your persistent disk while your application is running, the snapshot might not capture pending writes that are in transit from memory to disk." -- [Best practices for persistent disk snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/snapshot-best-practices#prepare_for_consistency). **This could lead to snapshots which aren't actually a good backup**, because the disk is in an unexpected state. The linked doc gives recommendations on pausing applications before snapshotting to ensure consistent backups.

Another option (for applications which support it), is to do application level backups using their tools. Databases, for example, usually have their own tooling for backups which understand application state and create reliable backups.

**Are GCE persistent disk snapshots different than VMWare snapshots?**

Yes, they are different. GCE PD doesn't stack deltas of the changes over time. The two systems use the word `snapshot`, but the underlying mechanism is different.

In VMWare, if you take multiple snapshots, each snapshot freezes the current disk state and future snapshots are based on the differences (deltas) from the previous ones, creating a chain of differences and the disk is the most recent state. A snapshot is a point in time of the evolution of the disk data. This allows directly rolling back the disk, but if you store a nightly snapshot as a backup, you can't just delete the old snapshots because new ones rely on the old ones. (There are options to compact them, though)

In Compute Engine, snapshots are separate objects and each snapshot is based on the state of the original disk at that time. A snapshot is a logical copy of the disk at a certain time. If you take nightly backups, you can delete old ones because they are independent from each other.

Also, Compute Engine snapshots are only snapshots of the disk, not the machine configuration. [Machine Images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-images) capture both machine configuration and the disk state.

Comment: Brian, GCE Linux snapshots are "crash" consistent and not "application" consistent. The state of these snapshots is the same as pulling the power on a computer. Any data in the file system, application memory, OS caching is lost which can result in severe corruption.

Comment: Good point. I addressed the specific question, but ignored the wider context of backups. I added a note on getting consistent backups with snapshots.